# Как менять язык гугл карты в зависимости от языка сайта на WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

есть гугл крата
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вставлена через Iframe
Все названия на русском. Как можно поменять язык карты если пользователь откроет En версию сайта

Пример Iframe

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2539.41961077153!2d30.517454615732117!3d50.47053157947815!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x40d4ce15c603724d%3A0x32fa3b78871b1de!2z0YPQuy4g0JLQtdGA0YXQvdC40Lkg0JLQsNC7LCA2NCwg0JrQuNC10LIsINCj0LrRgNCw0LjQvdCwLCAwMjAwMA!5e0!3m2!1sru!2sru!4v1580479727619!5m2!1sru!2sru?hl=en" style="border:0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Вордпресс тут не причем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определите язык сайта. В зависимости от того, чем сделана мультиязычность, способ определения разный. Обычно надо в url добавить строку такого вида `?hl=en`. В iframe несколько иначе, там в конце есть параметры языка `!1sru!2sru`.

Вот два iframe, которые показывают карту на английском и русском.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2539.41961077153!2d30.517454615732117!3d50.47053157947815!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x40d4ce15c603724d%3A0x32fa3b78871b1de!2z0YPQuy4g0JLQtdGA0YXQvdC40Lkg0JLQsNC7LCA2NCwg0JrQuNC10LIsINCj0LrRgNCw0LjQvdCwLCAwMjAwMA!5e0!3m2!1sru!2sru!4v1580479727619!5m2!1sen!2sen" style="border:0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2539.41961077153!2d30.517454615732117!3d50.47053157947815!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x40d4ce15c603724d%3A0x32fa3b78871b1de!2z0YPQuy4g0JLQtdGA0YXQvdC40Lkg0JLQsNC7LCA2NCwg0JrQuNC10LIsINCj0LrRgNCw0LjQvdCwLCAwMjAwMA!5e0!3m2!1sru!2sru!4v1580479727619!5m2!1sru!2sru" style="border:0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Comment: К сожалению ?hl=en в конце src никак не влияет не язык(

Comment: Ещё как влияет. Сравните две ссылки `https://www.google.ru/maps/@55.354135,40.297852,5z?hl=en` и `https://www.google.ru/maps/@55.354135,40.297852,5z?hl=ru`. И покажите ваш iframe в вопросе.

Comment: Добавил пример iframe

Comment: Добавил 2 проверенных iframe, которые показывают карту на разных языках.

Comment: Спасибо, работает